# Eclipse Open Type: Restrict to open project

Tags: java, eclipse

I frequently use the Eclipse "Open Type" dialog to quickly jump to classes.  The problem is, as I work on more and more projects in parallel, i.e. tackling different bugs in the same source code, the dialog sorts multiple copies of the same class in different projects by how frequently they've been opened, which means that I have to look around for my current project and make sure to open that type.  It's annoying, and often I forget to do it and find myself working on a class in a different project.

Is there a way to restrict the Open Type dialog to only show types from the project I am currently working in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "current project" changes infrequently enough, you can use the Working Set selector in the Open Type dialog. It's easy to change the Working Set to match your current context.

[image]

Another option is to close the projects you're not currently working with, which eliminates them from consideration in lots of places in the Eclipse UI.

If, however,  what you consider "current project" changes very frequently (like every few minutes) then neither of these options is very practical.